# Have an array of Asteroids, how can I loop them to infinitely spawn?

Tags: c#, xna, html-helper

I have made a game similar to asteroids and I have made an array of Asteroids controlled by an `int` count which i have made spawn 10 asteroids to the screen when the game starts.

What I'm wondering is how can I get the asteroids to spawn infinitely. I'm thinking of using a loop and have tried:

```
if (asteroidcount <= 5)
{
    asteroidcount += 10;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I am also using Visual Studio Express C# 2010

Comment: Is this C# or C++? How is the array of asteroids "controlled" by some unrelated integer?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to try a different approach. First you will need an asteroid class where you can store positions and other variables you may need.

```
public class Asteroid
{
       public Vector2 Velocity;
       public Vector2 Position;
       public Asteroid(Vector2 velocity, vector2 position)
       {
        Velocity = velocity;
        Position = position;
       }
}
```

Now add this `List` to your game, it will store all the asteroids. The reason I chose this over an array is it is much easier to change the size depending on how many asteroids you have.

```
List<Asteroid> Asteroids = new List<Asteroid>();
```

Now you can spawn 10 asteroids like this at the begining of your game

```
for (int i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
Asteroids.Add(new Asteroid(new Vector2(0,10), new Vector2(50,50)));
}
```

That will make an asteroid at position 50,50 with velocity of 10, so if you use my update code below it will move down with that velocity.

Now, for your actual problem, we need to spawn more when their are not enough (Player destroyed them I assume)

So, in your update method:

```
while (Asteroids.Count <5) //If there are less than 5 asteroids, add more
{
Asteroids.Add(new Asteroid(new Vector2(0,10), new Vector2(50,50)));
//Same thing as before, add asteroid
}
```

And there you go!

---

Here are some *extra* tips

If you want to draw all your asteroids, you need to make a method for it

```
 public void DrawAsteroid(Asteroid a)
 {
        spriteBatch.Draw(ASTEROID TEXTURE, a.Position, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
 }
```

now in your `Draw()` method you can add this

```
  spriteBatch.Begin();
  foreach (Asteroid a in Asteroids) //Draw each astroid
  {
       DrawAsteroid(a);
  }
  spriteBatch.End();
```

And you can use a simlar approach if you want to update all of the asteroids.
In `Update()`,

```
float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
foreach (Asteroid a in Asteroids) //Update each astroid
{
    UpdateAsteroid(a, elapsed);
}
```

And the method,

```
public void UpdateAsteroid(Asteroid a, float elapsed)
{
       a.Position += a.Velocity * elapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without more code or info about how your game works, but a guess would be this: You probably want to put more logic into a larger game loop and add more asteroids in every frame or time step in the game if the amount drops below a certain amount.

```
bool running = true;

while (running) 
{
    // Handle input etc
    // Handle game logic

    // Spawn more asteroids if there are too few of them!
    if (asteroidcount <= 5) 
    {
        asteroidcount += 10;
    }

    // Render

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do u have any tutorial links for this?